# Handling exceptions in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How am I supposed to handle exceptions in Objective-C? I am getting an `NSInvalidArgumentException` while coding; using breakpoints, I can figure out where the exception is happening. I tried something like this:

```
@try{ 
  //My code
}
@catch(id e){

}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: paste the actual error message into your question.

Comment: I've rewritten your question to resemble English, but I hope that I have preserved your initial point. Let me know if I've messed something up. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch an exception in objective-c you need to do this:

```
@try
{ 
  //Your code
}
@catch(NSException* e) // or subclass of NSException
{

}
```

**However** you do not want to catch an `NSInvalidArgumentException`, as it is indicative of a bug in your code.  As Ken says, it's effectively a controlled crash.  The most common cause of this exception is trying to insert `nil` into a colllection e.g. `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`.  If that is the problem, you can find it really easily by running your code in the debugger with "Stop on Objective-C exceptions" enabled.

Answer (score 3):

In Cocoa, you should think of an exception as a crash with extra information (with rare exceptions <- ha!).

You don't want to handle an NSInvalidArgumentException exception.  You want to understand why it happened and change your code such that it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the **Run** menu in XCode, an select **Stop on Objective-C Exceptions**.  Now your code will stop at the place that's actually throwing the exception, so you can see exactly what line triggered it.

Answer (score 1):

You should always strive to write code that will not generate exceptions. That said, you CAN handle exceptions on iOS. Read this blog st by Matt Gallagher: 
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html